# How with vararg return result on kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have a code like this but I don't understand where is the error?
The function should return the result of checking two words for matching characters in these words.

An unlimited number of arguments can be passed to the function

```
  fun howInTwoWords(vararg s:String): String {
    return s.split(" ").flatMap { it.toSet() }.groupBy { it }.filterValues { it.size > 1 }.keys.joinToString(separator = "")
}
fun main() {
    println(howInTwoWords("hello","world"));
}
```

**Example:**

**Input**:hello world

**Output**:lo

Comment: if the words are already splitted, what do you think should be removed?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As already stated, there's a function you don't need, we could tell you what is is, but instead, I'd _spit_ the problem into individual steps, so you can see the output of each function, then compare where in the "chain" it breaks. ;-)

Comment: split?))) 
aaaa I stupid, sorry please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need delete function split, because this function breaks one string on more string.

```
fun howInTwoWords(vararg s:String): String {
        return s.flatMap{ it.toSet() }.groupBy { it }.filterValues { it.size > 1 }.keys.joinToString(separator = "")
    }
    fun main() {
        println(howInTwoWords("hello","world"))
    }
```